# Multi-level mixed effects model - intercept insignificant

Tags: r, mixed-model, multiple-regression, multilevel-analysis, statsmodels

I am running a multi-level model in R, and the results suggest that the intercept is highly non-significant p = 0.9, but that two of the variables are significant. All the variables are Likert scores of mood and enjoyment.

Does this mean that I cannot interpret the effect of the predictors on the outcome variable?

Comment: Please provide more details about: the data, the variables (incl. the response) and the model. Also show us the results that you are trying to interpret. The meaning of the intercept is determined by all this information, not just its p-value.

Comment: The data is collected in an experience sampling method design where repeated measures are taken from participants 7 times day across 6 days. At each time-point mood data (positive / negative), pleasure in the form of anticipation, motivation and consummation, and current and predicted future activity are recorded. Pleasure and mood are recorded as likert variables (1 not at all - 7 very much so). The regression has consummatory pleasure as the outcome variable and time-lagged anticipation and unlagged positive mood as the predictor variables. The model is constructed with 3 levels beep,day,id.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't mean that at all. It simply means that there is insufficient evidence that the intercept is different from zero (I suppose you are talking about the global intercept, not group-specific intercepts of the mixed model). If that has any implications at all for your research question depends on the problem at hand. In many applications, in particular when you are only testing for the significance of some particular predictors, it doesn't matter. So a question to ask is: *Do you have any substantive reason to a priori think that the intercept should be zero?*

Importantly, the intercept is very sensitive to the scaling of your varibables, because *the intercept is the expected value of the outcome when all predictors are set at zero.*

So it is easily possible to transform your likert variables in a way which does not affect model fit or their significance, but will shift your intercept away from zero. You can try it out. For example, what happens to the model and p-value of the intercept when you add 10 to the predictor variables? (This will also depend on your model structure, which you should definitely report)

Comment: I suppose I would expect that if the predictor variables really do predict the outcome variable, as both are recorded on likert scales, that the intercept being 0 could even be considered a good thing? Maybe I am totally mis-interpreting that. At any rate, this is the Formula: consummation ~ lagged_anticipation + pos_mood + (lagged_anticipation + pos_mood  | beep number) +  
    (lagged_anticipation + pos_mood  | day number) + (lagged_anticipation + pos_mood  | participant number)

Comment: You could probably profit from writing out the model equation of the model you fitted. Then it will be easier to see what exactly the implications of the different parameters are for the predicted outcome. Also you shouldn't mix up the p-value for the intercept with the intercept parameter itself. Just that the data give little reason to believe that the intercept is different from zero does not mean that zero is indeed a likely value for the intercept. Maybe you can read up on some resources about linear (mixed) models